# Azure devops sql deployment (CD) issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl0TF.png)]

```
2023-10-19T13:31:25.4388982Z *** An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
2023-10-19T13:31:25.4389592Z Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:hrprocesses mld***02.
2023-10-19T13:31:25.6721607Z ##[error]Publishing to database 'grctrackertest' on server '10.**.**.33'.
```

I need to deploy on `10.**.***.33` server, where in the script the reference is used of `10.***.**.34` server and I am getting above error in azure classic editor CD pipeline

In case if I need to pass the argument, how to pass it in Azure DevOps classic editor pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:hrprocesses mld***02.

According to [SQLCMD Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver16#sqlcmd-variables), the format to use variables is `/v:{PropertyName}={Value}`.

To pass it in Azure SQL Database deployment task in the Azure DevOps classic editor pipeline, add the `/v:hrprocesses=somevalue /v:mld***02=anothervalue` to **Additional SqlPackage.exe Arguments**.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanx alot, it worked.